# PHP CURL request works on Ubuntu 12 and 13 not Ubuntu 14

Tags: php, curl

The following code works on Ubuntu versions below 14:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$serverOutput = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This starts to run on Ubuntu 14 but times out on curl_exec. Have tried on two Ubuntu 14 boxes and neither are connecting properly.

Is there some configuration change or extra option for php5 on Ubuntu 14 that needs to be made to allow this to connect?

---

Output of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying IP ADDRESS...
* Connected to example.com (IP ADDRESS) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

does not get any further.

Comment: First of all give us more information about the error. Use `curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and `curl_error()`. 
Also there is a possibility that the problem is on you webserver (i.e apache) configuration. If your server is behind a proxy, apache must be aware of that and redirect the traffic

Comment: So, where is the `time_out`, I am not seeing any problem with the output

Comment: The script does not produce anymore output, CApath is the last line printed out. The only way to get any more output is to add the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT option. With this option set to 30 seconds the script terminates after that without returning any data.